# How do I make the text section writeable in GDB?

Tags: gdb, elf

I am running an elf in GDB and would like to have the executing code write to the text section.  I could do this from the shell like:

```
set {int}[text_address] = 0x8008face
```

But executing an instruction to write to this address bombs out.

I'd rather not modify the elf, but instead set a range of addresses to rwx on the fly.

Edit: I should mention, this is running simulated, not native.

Comment: Have you tried to call the `mprotect` from GDB to make the page writable?

Comment: Added an edit, probably should have mentioned this is simulated since it's not x86. I called the mprotect equivalent and it didn't make text writeable. Thanks, that probably would have worked native.

Comment: You may have  to tell the simulator to put the code into RAM instead of ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke GDB with the `--write` flag.

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#index-_002d_002dwrite) says: "Open the executable and core files for both reading and writing. This is equivalent to the ‘set write on’ command inside GDB (see Patching).", but I don't believe they are actually equivalent.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45340590/50617) for an example.